# debugging wordpress

Tags: debug

I noticed that when I'm working on a php page that loads wp programmatically, some of my errors are not fired. For example, a variables that has not initialized previously creates a warning when I have the E_ALL on top, but not when I load wp after that.

Any comments?

how do I put wordpress  in a mode so that anything wrong anywhere is reported.

Comment: http://debugggg.wordpress.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you set `WP_DEBUG` to `true` in `wp-config.php` it should output all your errors. Alternatively, you can use something like [Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/) or [BlackBox](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/blackbox-debug-bar/) to display the errors. How much you need should determine your solution.